# What is the difference between using a var statement with multiple values separated by commas and multiple var statements?

Tags: javascript

*What is the difference between a semicolon and the separate*?

ex: ***semicolon***

```
 var name = 'Ali';
 var age = 24;
```

ex: ***separate***

```
 var name = 'Ali', age = 24;
```

Comment: There is no difference, both declare multiple variables. There is no performance  difference, and the semicolons are not required either.

Comment: Semicolon marks the end of a statement, in JavaScript a semi-colon can be optional, according to your layout, it must be used to delimit statements.   A common just delimits statements of the same type.